# Run PowerPoint Macro from PowerShell

Tags: vba, powershell, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint with the following macro:

```vb
Sub test()
    MsgBox "testing"
End Sub
```

And a PowerShell script like this:

```bsh
$ppt = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
$presentation = $ppt.Presentations.Open("test.pptm")
$ppt.Run("test")
```

But running the macro just gives:

```
Cannot find an overload for "Run" and the argument count: "1".
At line:1 char:1
+ $ppt.Run("test")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

I get the same error for e.g. `$presentation.application.run("test")` and
`$ppt.Run("test.pptm!test")`.

Related:

[Calling Excel macros from PowerShell with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536241/calling-excel-macros-from-powershell-with-arguments)

[Passing a variant through COM object via PowerShell to run a macro in PowerPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579974/passing-a-variant-through-com-object-via-powershell-to-run-a-macro-in-powerpoint)

The documentation suggests that `Run` should just take the macro name as a string as its first argument, so I can't see where I'm going wrong.

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
System.Object Run(string MacroName, [ref] Params System.Object[] safeArrayOfParams)
System.Object _Application.Run(string MacroName, [ref] Params System.Object[] safeArrayOfParams)
```

[Application.Run Method (PowerPoint)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff744221.aspx)

Comment: Try passing an empty array as the second parameter?
You might have to do "ModuleName.SubName" as the first param by the way

Comment: I've resolved my issue using Invoke-NamedParameter from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544844/how-to-call-a-complex-com-method-from-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ppt = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
$presentation = $ppt.presentations.Open("test.pptm")
$ppt.Run("test", @())
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives: $ppt.Run("test", @())
type must not be ByRef
At line:1 char:1
+ $ob = $ppt.Run("test", @())
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException

Comment: Can you try with `$ppt.Run("test", [ref]@())`?

Comment: ISTR that you can call public subs in add-ins using just the name of the sub (ie, .Run("test") but if you want to call a sub from within a loaded PPT/PPTM file you need to use something like .Run("Test.pptm!test")

Comment: Both behave the same on my computer. When sub is not found, you get this error: `Application.Run : Invalid request.  Sub or function not defined.`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/654e81a7-e998-4575-9261-ad4d2507117a/how-to-invoke-ms-access-vba-function?forum=winserverpowershell):

```
$ppt = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
$presentation = $ppt.Presentations.Open("test.pptm")
$presname = $presentation.Name
$VBScript = New-Object -ComObject "MSScriptControl.ScriptControl"
$VBscript.Language = "VBScript"
$VBscript.AddCode( 
@"
  Function RunVBA( app, functionName ) 
    RunVBA = app.Run( functionName, array() )
  End Function
"@
)

$VBscript.CodeObject.RunVBA( $ppt, "$presname!test" )
```

Note that this only works with Powershell x86, since ScriptControl is not available in a 64-bit environment.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the Application object via the presentation works for me:

```
$ppt = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
$presentation = $ppt.Presentations.Open("test.pptm")
$presentation.Application.Run("test")
```